# Conditional substitution of union member in C

Tags: c

I have

```
typedef union 
{
    void (*fp1p)(void);
    void (*fp2p)(uint32_t);
    void (*fp3p)(uint32_t, uint32_t);
    void (*fp4p)(uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t);
    uint32_t (*fp5p)(uint32_t);
    uint32_t (*fp6p)(uint32_t, uint32_t);
    uint32_t (*fp7p)(uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t);
} fp;
struct command
{
    char *name;  //command name
    uint32_t minargs;
    uint32_t maxargs;
    int minval;
    int maxval;
    fp read_func_pointer;
    fp write_func_pointer;
};

struct command commands[] = 
{
    [0] = { "reg1001", 0,0,0,0, .read_func_pointer.fp6p = TDC1000_SPIByteReadReg, .write_func_pointer.fp4p = TDC1000_SPIByteWriteReg },
    //
   //
   };
```

And then

```
if(condition)
{
   uint32_t ret_val = commands[0].read_func_pointer.fp6p(…);
}
else
{
   commands[0]. write_func_pointer.fp6p(…);
}
```

How can I make it generic instead of .fp6p?

Comment: Your question is not clear. A command can use any of these 7 different methods, using zero to three arguments. From where are the values coming to call the read or write method?

Comment: That’s the catch – how to “feed” the write pointer according to some condition/case.

Comment: What is the source of the data? From where do you get the zero, one, two or three values which are used to call the functions? What is the final goal of this generic calling?

Comment: Well…In my command structure I can create a variable like pointer_type and then in switch(pointer_type)  go through all cases and set the pointer in its case. But I was looking for more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if thats an option for you, but how about adding an enum representing the function pointer type to your struct?

In the conditon statement you could switch on the enum and then call the right function pointer.

Comment: It’s a straightforward method. I thought there is more elegant one.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a more elegant method. However, you could use the concept of [variadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) to write a wrapper function to which you could pass a variable number of args. One problem would still remain though: The different return values (void or uint32).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use anonymous members for unions:

```
struct command
{
    char *name;  //command name
    ...
    union 
    {
        ....
        void (*fp4p)(uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t);
        uint32_t (*fp6p)(uint32_t, uint32_t);
    };
    ...
};
```

You have to change `fp6p`, etc. names to `fp6pw` for write_func members. Then call directly `commands[0].fp6p(...)`. Not sure but initialization must be "generic" as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to clarify.
Suppose we have several commands

```
struct command commands[] = {
 [0] = { "reg1001", 0,0,0,0, .read_func_pointer.fp6p =      TDC1000_SPIByteReadReg, .write_func_pointer.fp4p = TDC1000_SPIByteWriteReg },
   [1] = = { "reg7201", 0,0,0,0, .read_func_pointer.fp3p =   TDC7200_SPIByteReadReg, .write_func_pointer.fp5p = TDC7200_SPIByteWriteReg },
};
```

I have a generic function to choose an incoming command

```
For (i=0; I < sizeof(commands); i++)
{
    if (strcmp(commands[i].name,args[0])==0)
    {
        commands[i]. read_func_pointer.<- Here – how can I know what    pointer to place?
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ok, this is useful information. So you get the input values from an array of `const char*`? Like the command line arguments? And you would like to map the first argument to a given call with 1-3 parameters. I would create a new question and add this context to the question. It seems to me, you just search for a good design. And for this case there are plenty good design alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. As I suspected – I should look for a better design.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function of signature known only at runtime is not achievable in portable standard C99 or C11; the signature should be known at compile time (and you could extend your code, conceptually by having a [tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) of function pointers, that is by keeping a tag describing the signature). This is so because the [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) can (and do) vary with the function signature (the ABI would use different registers for passing different kinds or types of arguments or results).

Alternatively, consider using [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/); it contains some magic (assembler code, dependent of the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)), which invokes an *arbitrary* function pointer whose signature is *described* by some meta-data.

If you are targetting POSIX, you could use some [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) & [dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) tricks (you might also consider plugin support in frameworks like [Qt5](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/)...). You might generate (at runtime) some appropriate (glue) C code in `generated-code-001.c`, compile it by forking some compiler command (e.g. `gcc -Wall -O -fPIC generated-code-001.c -shared -o generated-code-001.so`), then `dlopen` that `./generated-code-001.so` shared object (on Linux; on MacOSX the compilation command and the file extension are different), and use `dlsym` to get the function pointer. I am extensively using such tricks in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)

Comment: I see. Thank you. It's better to implement switch-case method then.

Comment: I would recommend instead using `libffi`

Comment: It’s an embedded application. I’m limited in resources.

Comment: AFAIK, `libffi` is quite small (31Kbytes on my Linux/x86-64). You probably won't do better.

Comment: My chip flash is 256kb  - so 31kb quite a chunk. :)  And the command parser is a small part of the program. :)